# how to modify hover info for plotly with ggplot geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am having trouble using this approach to specify the traces and control the hover displays with a `geom_smooth` plot.  There are many similar questions answered here (most related is [ggplotly - only return tooltip hover text on certain geom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004936/ggplotly-only-return-tooltip-hover-text-on-certain-geom-objects/70221615#70221615)) but the solutions don't seem to work in my case.

**Goal:** display only the `y` value in the tooltip for all of the smoother lines (mean and both se)

**Problem:** the trace for the smoother mean line seems to be 4, and for the smoother se lines seems to be 5.  But changing the `hoverinfo` for 4 does nothing, and changing the `hoverinfo` for 5 changes the tooltip for the smoother mean, but not the smoother se

Reprex below, followed by screenshots of the problem

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(listviewer)

y <- c(2,7,3,4,2,4,5,5,1,4,4,7,4,2,2,3,7,4,1,3,6,11,3,4,3,3,3,2,0,2,1,0,3,1,1,2)
x <- c(lubridate::ymd("2018-12-01"),
       lubridate::ymd(paste0("2019-", seq(1, 12, 1), "-01")),
       lubridate::ymd(paste0("2020-", seq(1, 12, 1), "-01")),
       lubridate::ymd(paste0("2021-", seq(1, 11, 1), "-01")))
       
       
df <- tibble(date=x, count=y) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date),
         month.abb = month.abb[lubridate::month(date)])

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = count))  +
  geom_point(size=1.5, shape=21, stroke=0.25,
             aes(fill = factor(year),
                 text = paste0(month.abb, ": ", count))) +
  geom_smooth(span=.8, col="grey")

plotly_json(ggplotly(p)) # to identify the traces

# only demonstrating the effect of changing trace 5
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>% 
  style(hoverinfo = "y", traces = 5)
```

Screenshots

This shows the smoother mean would appear to be trace 4, but changing trace 5 hoverinfo controls the display, setting it to show "y" only

[image: smoother mean]

This shows the smoother se would appear to be trace 5, but changing trace 5 hoverinfo has no effect on the display for the se lines

[image: smoother se]